# Can we eat in a Sukkah standing?

Tags: halacha, sukkot, sukkah, eating, standing-sitting

I know we say "sit in a Sukkah", but still I have following question:

- if we have guests during Sukkot and we want them to eat with us in a Sukkah, but a Sukkah is too small to fit everyone in seated, would it be ok to serve meal in buffet-style, so that people keep standing and everybody will serve himself?

I have found similar question "[Forbidden to eat while standing up?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15580/forbidden-to-eat-while-standing-up)", but there it is recommended to always sit while eating, if you are a Talmid Chacham. But none of us is really a scholar, so I need some advice for "ordinary people", family and friends.

Comment: So you're asking answerers to ignore any issues of generally eating while standing? (If so, you might wish to [edit the question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/18524/edit) to more explicitly indicate as much.)

Comment: @msh210 well, I understood the general problem is only for scholars to eat while standing.

Comment: Maybe so. So you're asking answerers to ignore any issues of generally eating while standing? (If so, you might wish to edit the question to more explicitly indicate as much.)

Comment: @msh210: not always at my best with my English language skills :-) Is it better now?

Comment: By the way, if you're serving buffet-style, then for intermediate days (or if you have an eiruv then all days) you can set up the buffet *outside* the sukkah and have more room for people to bring their plates inside the sukkah to eat (whether they then stand or sit).  The requirement to be inside the sukkah is on the people, not on the food.

Comment: TomBerger, IMO yes. Thanks. @MonicaCellio, yeah, but people (or at least men) have to be careful to eat only in the _suka_.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's not so simple as that, cf Mishna Sukka 2:7 which is one of the 6? places we rule like Beit Shammai.

Comment: @msh210 Also I imagine one could make an argument for being mitztaer if he has to eat in a crowded sukkah while standing and could thus potentially eat outside anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can eat in a sukkah standing up (as regards the lawa of sukkot). The word 'sitting' is used to imply a sort of permanence of dwelling, but if one eats in a sukkah while standing he certainly says a bracha and fulfils his mitzva. (See [Aruch Hashulchan OC 643:3](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%92))