# What is the source of the prohibition against "eating or drinking while standing", mentioned in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, eating, shulchan-aruch, standing-sitting

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 42:2 states that - "One shouldn't eat while standing and not drink while standing."

Now as I understand, the Kitzur (written by Rabbi Shlomo Ganzfried) is a summary of the Shulchan Aruch, which in turn is largely based on the Beit Yosef, which is a commentary on the Arba'ah Turim.

**Is this prohibition mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch, Beit Yosef, Tur or any other work? Or did Rabbi Ganzfried add it based on his own knowledge?**

*This is a related question which was asked on Mi Yodeya, however it does not mention the verse in the Kitzur. 
[Forbidden to eat while standing up?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15580/forbidden-to-eat-while-standing-up)*

Comment: Re "as I understand, the Kitzur... is a summary of the Shulchan Aruch": That's not my understanding at all. He writes practical _halacha_ including things noted by later authorities like _Magen Avraham_.

Comment: @msh210 Rabbi Shlomo Ganzfried  did however state that there should be no commentaries on his work, since its point, as indicated by its title, was that it should remain short – and that such commentaries should be appended to the Shulchan Aruch itself, rather than to the Kitzur. This would indicate that the Kitzur was intended as a summary/abridgement of the Shulchan Aruch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source for this is the Masechet Derech Eretz; one of the minor tractates (4:1):

> מי שהוא תלמיד חכם, לא יאכל מעומד, ולא ישתה מעומד, ולא יקנח את הקערה, ולא ילקק באצבעותיו, ולא יגהק בפני חבירו, מיעוט שיחה, מיעוט שחוק, מיעוט שינה, מיעוט תענוג, מיעוט הן הן, מיעוט לאו לאו

It gives a list of personal habits that Torah scholars should adopt including not eating and drinking while standing.

This is mentioned in many post-Talmudic sources and was not made up by R. Ganzfreid. Such as the Rambam (De'ot 4:3) the Hagahot of *Rama* to the Mordechai in B'rachot (ch. Keitzad Mevarchim: remez 145).

It should be noted that Rambam writes merely that a person should do so; not that it is prohibited to do otherwise.

It should be noted that much of Hilchot De'ot of the Rambam is quoted almost verbatim by the Kitzur.

This advice is notably absent from the *Shulchan Aruch*.

Comment: The preexisting question (linked to from this one) already asks for sources; this question asks specifically for the **_Kitzur_'s** source. Do you have any evidence for saying that _Derech Eretz_ is his source?

Comment: @msh210 as the kitzut does not give the source it is theoretically impossible to know whether he based himself off the Talmudic sources, made it up himself, or was taught it by extremely wise space squids. The most we can do is document the evidence. This seems to be the main thrust of the question as the OP wrote in bold **Is this prohibition mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch, Beit Yosef, Tur or any other work? Or did Rabbi Ganzfried add it based on his own knowledge?**

Comment: Well, if you're right that he's just seeking sources, and not the _Kitzur_'s source, then this is clearly a duplicate of the preexisting question. I mean, it's exactly the same question, then.

Comment: @msh210 The main purpose behind asking the question wasn't to know the Kitzur's source but to know whether the source is the Shulchan Aruch. Thankfully this has been made clear by mevaqesh.

Answer (score 4):

It would seem that the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (d. 1886) is quoting theBe'er Heitev in Siman 170 [סימן קע - דברי מוסר שינהג אדם בסעדה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_14.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2) who says:

> **באר היטב  (טז) עמהם**. אפי' בסעודת מצוה. מט''מ: (עי' בס' **אליהו רבה** שמביא בשם **של''ה** כמה דיני מוסר בסעודה וכתב בשם **רוקח**: דרך ארץ **לא יאכל אדם מעומד ולא ישתה מעומד** ולא יקנח הקערה כו' ולא יעמוד מיד אחר הסעודה ולכל מין מאכל ישהא אחריו כשיעור ברכה אחרונה שלו. איתא במסכת דרך ארץ לא ישמח אדם בין הבוכים ולא יבכה בין השמחים ולא יהיה ער בין הישנים ולא ישן בין הערים ולא יושב בין העומדים ולא עומד בין היושבים כללא של דבר אל ישנה אדם דעתו מדעת חבירו ובני אדם. ולא יישן אחר אכילה מיד ועי' ברמב''ם הלכות דעות שהאריך בדברים אלו והנהגתן): ‏

"The Be'er Heitev (d. 1723) quotes the Eliyahu Raba (d. 1712) who is quoting the Shla"h (d. 1630) who is quoting the Roke'ach (d. 1240) - it's good manners not to eat while standing and not to drink while standing," etc.

Comment: How do you know isn't coming off the DE Zuta, Gemara Gittin, and Rambam De'os? The only part of the Shla he quotes is the part that is a direct quotation of the DE Zuta.

Comment: Because he's using the same words... לֹא יֹאכַל מְעֻמָּד וְלֹא יִשְׁתֶּה מְעֻמָּד as opposed to being implied by  DE Zuta, Gemara Gittin, and Rambam De'os who say things to the effect of לְעוֹלָם כְּשֶׁיֹּאכַל אָדָם יֵשֵׁב בִּמְקוֹמוֹ אוֹ יִטֶּה עַל שְׂמֹאל

Comment: Could someone please translate that? I don't know Hebrew.

Comment: I translated the relevant piece. The rest is pasted for completeness.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Thank you Danny, much appreciated.