# Eating/Drinking while standing - Seder?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, minhag, yetziat-mitzrayim

Edited for clarity:

The question providing a source to the prohibition of eating and drinking while standing has been discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64705/what-is-the-source-of-the-prohibition-against-eating-or-drinking-while-standing?noredirect=1&lq=1) and in subsequent links. In both posts phenomenal sources were given to support halachically where this minhag/halacha originates. But my question is *where from the Torah do we find this?*

Shemos Rabbah 20:18 discusses the cognitive relationship of ויסב as הסיבה reclining (Maharzu). The following is derived from Toldos Noach, Beur Maharif, Eitz Yosef:

> When the people were freed they had the opportunity to recline while
>   dining, unlike slaves who must eat while standing on their feet or
>   walking from place to place.

**Does anyone use the historical behavior of slaves as a source for this minhag (derived from the Torah)? Do we not stand while eating/drinking to remember yetziat mitzrayim?**

Answer (score 3):

This is found in the Yerushalmi in the beginning of Arvei Pesachim

> אמר רב לוי ולפי שדרך עבדים להיות אוכלין מעומד וכאן להיות אוכלין מסובין להודיע שיצאו מעבדות לחירות.

Rav Levi said: And since common practice of slaves is to eat while standing, and here to eat while reclining, to make known (our) having gone out from slavery to freedom.

*My translation*

Comment: This is certainly the source of the pirush he quotes. As such I think it answers both parts of his question. The Yerushalmi uses this idea as the source and that it why we do it, at least according to the Yerushalmi.

Comment: @user6591 mind editing and translating into English. My Hebrew is rusty....

Comment: I'm confused (perhaps about the question) but I thought he was seeking a source that the general 'prohibition' against eating while standing was due to this connection, but this source seems to indicate the reason for leaning on Pesach is due to this connection.

Comment: @Double I'm confused about your confusion. The word sedder in the title and hesseiba in the body clearly show what he is discussing. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: @user6591 I thought he was saying "Eating while standing: [do we learn it from the] Seder?"  He says pretty clearly that "This question has been discussed [at a link discussing eating while standing in general]"

Comment: @Double Oh. I hear you now. Could very well be...